# how can i change VLC media player interface

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

is there a way I can change the VLC media player icons?

I'm looking for something decent, nice and modern. they seemed to get it right on the android app, but the desktop version seemed to not have changed for the past 10 years.

all the skins seem to also be outdated, or they stick to a specific theme too much, I'm looking for just a nice media player interface.

I don't even want to make a whole new skin, I just want to know how to make some tweaks, like changing the play and pause icons, and maybe also the VLC icon. or if there is already a "normal" skin out there, with the overall vlc theme, like the app interface (not exactly, and I hope you get what om trying to put out there) on pc.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't want to make a new skin, you'll need to open the default.vlt skin file with [Skin Editor](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/skineditor.html).

Have a play around, and see what assets you can change.

Comment: ok, but the default skin file is a different skin than the regular skin, on vlc I guess it's considered the native skin (that's what it's called in preferences), how can I access the native skin file and edit that?

Comment: https://forum.videolan.org/